# Android setOnClickListener disables state color change in ListView

Tags: android, colors, state, onclicklistener

I have a simple ListView, and by default when I press on list item its background changes to some color. But when I assign each list item view .setOnClickListener(...) it stops doing that.
Could you tell me what is going behind the scenes ? I've looked into this method and it's not a plain setter, it's a chain of scary method invocations...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you shouldn't be setting an `OnClickListener` for every item in your list. You should set an `OnItemClickListener` on your `ListView`, which will callback when items are pressed. Try something like this instead:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            // When clicked, show a toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position 
                            + " clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```